# Making CRUD in Liferay MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, liferay

i'm creating a portlet in java. I have build a class Student. I have a databse and i want to make CRUD operations. I made only read and add methods. Can anybody help me in update and delete? i don't know how to get the id of student so i update that record, or i delete it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
public class Student extends base.persistence.Entity {

private String firstName;
private int age;
private Date birthDate;
private String gender;
private boolean isfreshman;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public Date getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}
public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}


public boolean isIsfreshman() {
    return isfreshman;
}
public void setIsfreshman(boolean isfreshman) {
    this.isfreshman = isfreshman;
}
@Id
@Override
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
@Override
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;

}
@Override
public Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}
@Override
public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}
@Override
public Date getDateUpdated() {  
    return dateUpdated;
}
@Override
public void setDateUpdated(Date dateUpdated) {
    this.dateUpdated = dateUpdated;

}
@Override
public boolean isDeleted() {
    return deleted;
}
@Override
public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
    this.deleted= deleted;
}
```

}

```
public class StudentMVCPortlet extends MVCPortlet{


   @Override
   public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)   throws     IOException, PortletException {
    List<Student> students = EntityUtil.getAll(Student.class);
    renderRequest.setAttribute("students", students);
    include("/list.jsp", renderRequest, renderResponse);
    //super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}

/*@Override
public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    PortletPreferences preferences = actionRequest.getPreferences();
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay =
            (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setId(EntityUtil.generateNewId());

    SessionMessages.add(actionRequest,"success");

    super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse);
}*/

@ProcessAction(name="addStudent")
public void addStudent(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    Student s = new Student();
    s.setFirstName(ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "firstName"));
    s.setAge(ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "age"));
    s.setGender(ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "gender"));
    s.setBirthDate(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest,"dateBirth",      DateFormatter.getSlashDelimeterDMYdateFormat()));
      s.setDateCreated(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest,"dateCreated",DateFormatter.getSlashDelimeterDMYdateFormat()));
    s.setDateUpdated(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest,"dateUpdated",DateFormatter.getSlashDelimeterDMYdateFormat()));
    s.setIsfreshman(ParamUtil.getBoolean(actionRequest, "isfreshman"));
    s.setDeleted(false);
    EntityUtil.save(s);
}
@ProcessAction(name="getStudent")
public void getStudent(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
     Student student = (Student) EntityUtil.getById(Student.class,(Long) renderRequest.getAttribute("id"));
    renderRequest.setAttribute("student", student);
    include("/edit.jsp", renderRequest, renderResponse);
    //super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}


@ProcessAction(name="updateStudent")
public void updateStudent(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException{
    Student student = (Student) EntityUtil.getById(Student.class, (Long) actionRequest.getAttribute("id"));
    student.setFirstName(ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "firstName"));
    student.setAge(ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "age"));
    student.setGender(ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "gender"));
    student.setBirthDate(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest,"dateBirth", DateFormatter.getSlashDelimeterDMYdateFormat()));
    student.setDateCreated(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest,"dateCreated",DateFormatter.getSlashDelimeterDMYdateFormat()));
    student.setDateUpdated(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest,"dateUpdated",DateFormatter.getSlashDelimeterDMYdateFormat()));
    student.setIsfreshman(ParamUtil.getBoolean(actionRequest, "isfreshman"));
    student.setDeleted(false);
    EntityUtil.save(student);

}
```

}

Comment: Are you using the service builder?

Comment: no, im not using it. im using hibernate

Comment: You'll need to create your Hibernate DAO to make transactions with your database. If you are using the same database as liferay, i'd recommend using the service builder. It will create the model and services for you.

Comment: Im using another database and i must use hibernate.

Comment: what does your stack trace show?

Comment: i don't know to how make the delete and update. how to pick the id of the row i have clicked

Comment: send the ID in and set it as hidden in your presentation layer. that way you can bring the id through your actionRequest

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some fundamental understanding about how to pass around the proper ids. My recommendation is to build this portlet, including the entity, with [xmlportletfactory](http://www.xmlportletfactory.org). That one will use servicebuilder, but generate all of the code that you currently are implementing on your own, including the frontend portlet. You can take a look at this code, debug and inspect it. Then transfer your findings to the code that you mention in your question - stepping through the code might help more than anyone describing some mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problems. here are all the methods i have used, not using service builder.

```
 public class StudentMVCPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

@Override
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest,
        RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    List<Student> students = EntityUtil.getAll(Student.class);
    renderRequest.setAttribute("students", students);
    include("/list.jsp", renderRequest, renderResponse);
    // super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}

@ProcessAction(name = "EditForm")
public void EditForm(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    Long id = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "id");
    Student student = (Student) EntityUtil.getById(Student.class, id);
    actionRequest.setAttribute("student", student);
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("mvcPath", "/edit.jsp");
}

@ProcessAction(name = "addStudent")
public void addStudent(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    Student s = new Student();
    s.setFirstName(ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "firstName"));
    s.setAge(ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "age"));
    String gender = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "gender");
    if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        gender = "null";
    }
    // s.setGender(ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "gender"));
    s.setGender(gender);
    s.setBirthDate(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest, "dateBirth",
            DateFormatter.getMinusDelimeterYMDdateFormat()));
    s.setDateCreated(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest, "dateCreated",
            DateFormatter.getMinusDelimeterYMDdateFormat()));
    s.setDateUpdated(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest, "dateUpdated",
            DateFormatter.getMinusDelimeterYMDdateFormat()));
    s.setIsfreshman(ParamUtil.getBoolean(actionRequest, "isfreshman"));
    s.setDeleted(false);
    EntityUtil.save(s);
}

@ProcessAction(name = "updateStudent")
public void updateStudent(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    Long id = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "id");
    Student dbStudent = (Student) EntityUtil.getById(Student.class, id);

    dbStudent.setFirstName(ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "firstName"));
    dbStudent.setAge(ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "age"));
    dbStudent.setGender(ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "gender"));
    dbStudent.setBirthDate(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest, "birthDate",
            DateFormatter.getMinusDelimeterYMDdateFormat()));
    dbStudent.setDateCreated(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest,
            "dateCreated", DateFormatter.getMinusDelimeterYMDdateFormat()));
    dbStudent.setDateUpdated(ParamUtil.getDate(actionRequest,
            "dateUpdated", DateFormatter.getMinusDelimeterYMDdateFormat()));
    dbStudent.setIsfreshman(ParamUtil.getBoolean(actionRequest,
            "isfreshman"));

    boolean save = EntityUtil.save(dbStudent);
    if (!save) {
        actionRequest.setAttribute("student", dbStudent);
        actionResponse.setRenderParameter("mvcPath", "/edit.jsp");
    }

}

@ProcessAction(name = "deleteStudent")
public void deleteStudent(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    Long id = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "id");
    Student dbStudent = (Student) EntityUtil.getById(Student.class, id);
    EntityUtil.trash(dbStudent);

}
```